# Forms: Checkboxes , name attribute - passing an array

Tags: php, xhtml

I have a checkbox coded in HTML, so far everything works, however I need to pass in an array in the name attribute of the checkboxes. I know its easy enough to do when you pass a variable into the name attribute. But for arrays it is proving tricker.

Here is my code:

```
   <?php // spit out rest of the list
       $permiCheck = array();
       foreach($pList as $value){
        //go into array, get what is needed to pass into the name attribute
        echo '<tr>';

        echo '<td>';
        echo $value['PName'];
        echo '</td>';
        //pass an array in
        $permiCheck['Id'] = $value['Id'];
        $permiCheck['ItemId'] = $value['ItemId'];
        if($value['Id']!=null) {



        ?>
        <td style="text-align:center;"> <input type="checkbox" checked="yes" name="<?php $permiCheck;?>" value="" id="change"></td>
```

After I have done this I intend to retrieve what was in the array via the POST method for form validation.

Any idea how I can do that, many thanks.

Comment: Give the checkbox a name that ends with []. When PHP receives it, it automatically interprets it as an array.

Comment: I am passing the PHP array ($permiCheck) which is a 2d Array into the name attribute. Will that still apply?

Comment: it won't apply because you can't pass an array into the attribute. please read comments below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the checkbox element has to be a string, you can however use checkboxes as an array.
i.e.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxName[]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxName[]" value="2"/>
```

will return

```
var_dump($_POST)

array
  'checkboxName' => 
    array
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 2
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but maybe you could do it this way

```
<td style="text-align:center;">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="yes" name="<?=$permiCheck['ItemId']?>[]" value="<?=$permiCheck['Id']?>" id="change">
</td>
```

Comment: yeah you are right, seem to have got the two mixed up. I think I am interested in passing the array into the value field, for later retrieval via the post method

Comment: you might want to use value="<?=$permiCheck['ItemId']?>_<?=$permiCheck['Id']?>" in your checkbox element in that case, and later on explode it when you're fetching the $_POST

Comment: Yeah I see what you are doing, you use explode to seperate it using the '_' as a guide? So the value attribute cannot pass arrays, all you can do is concatenate strings like that?

Comment: Thanks, one more question; when I submit the checkboxes to PHP, it only sends the checkboxes which have been ticked over to PHP, and not the unticked ones, is there anyway to send both states over in the POST variable?

Comment: Nevermind, I have solved it: <input type="hidden" name="myArray[]" value="0" /> will get both states and pass it to the $_POST variable. When it is not checked and when it is checked.

Answer (score 1):

For a variable:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myVariable" />
```

For an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myArray[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myArray[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myArray[]" />
```

Hope this solves the mistery ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can pass arrays as values, and those can even be multidimensional:

```
<?
$testarray = array('id'=> 1, 'value'=>"fifteen");
var_dump($_POST);
?>
<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" checked="yes" name="permicheck[id1]" value="<?php print_r($testarray)?>" id="change">
<input type="checkbox" checked="yes" name="permicheck[id2]" value="<?php print_r($testarray)?>" id="change">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

It produces HTML output as follows:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" checked="yes" name="permicheck[id1]" value="Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [value] => fifteen
)
" id="change">
<input type="checkbox" checked="yes" name="permicheck[id2]" value="Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [value] => fifteen
)
" id="change">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And $_POST looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [permicheck] => 
        Array ( 
        [id1] =>
            Array ( [id] => 1 [value] => fifteen ) 
        [id2] => 
            Array ( [id] => 1 [value] => fifteen ) 
        )
     )
```

However, doing this exposes your info to outsiders, which is generally bad, since it can expose you to web attacks. I'd recommend to store this array in $_SESSION and use simple check on those checkboxes; if that's not possible, consider using serialize() and some encryption, and then decrypting + unserialize() after you've received $_POST. It requires more work, but is much safer.